# Communicating data between all users with a database

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a program for my company that will be used to communicate various information between users, among other things that aren't important at the moment. One of the things that is going to be communicated is a daily tasks checklist. Basically, the intent is to have a check list that syncs between all users, so if one user checks off a task, everyone else can see that the task has been completed.

So far what I have done is I have created a DataGrid object to hold the check boxes. The box starts empty, but when the program loads, the following code is run, which populates the list.

```
Private Sub chkListPop()
    If System.IO.File.Exists(chkListPath) Then
        Dim newChk As CheckBox
        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBooks As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
        Dim r As Byte
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(chkListPath)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBooks.Worksheets("Tasks")
        rng = xlWorkSheet.Range("A2")
        r = 0
        Do While rng.Offset(r).Value <> ""
            chkListContainer.Items.Add(New Controls.CheckBox)
            newChk = chkListContainer.Items.Item(r)
            newChk.Content = rng.Offset(r).Value
            Try
                If rng.Offset(r, 1).Value = True Then
                    newChk.IsChecked = True
                End If
            Catch
            End Try
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks.Save()
        xlWorkBooks.Close()
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, the sub reads an excel file and, for each line in the file, creates a checkbox with the true false value in the second column. I imagine there has to be a more elegant solution to do this. I am not a programmer by training, so I have limited knowledge on topics this "complex". Whats a better way to do this other than using an excel file? Should I use an Access database or and SQL database instead? This code works, but I just feel like its wrong somehow.

Additionally, I am having trouble figuring out how to update the file when someone checks off a task. For now I just have a timer running, and every X minutes, the program updates the excel file. Here's the code for how that works:

```
Public Sub chkListSendData()
    If System.IO.File.Exists(chkListPath) Then
        Dim newChk As CheckBox
        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBooks As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
        Dim r As Byte
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(chkListPath)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBooks.Worksheets("Tasks")
        rng = xlWorkSheet.Range("A2")
        r = 0
        Do While rng.Offset(r).Value <> ""
            Try
                newChk = chkListContainer.Items.Item(r)
            Catch
                chkListContainer.Items.Add(New Controls.CheckBox)
                newChk = chkListContainer.Items.Item(r)
                newChk.Content = rng.Offset(r).Value
            End Try
            If newChk.IsChecked Then
                rng.Offset(r, 1).Value = True
            End If
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks.Save()
        xlWorkBooks.Close()
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub chkListGetData()
    If System.IO.File.Exists(chkListPath) Then
        Dim newChk As CheckBox
        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBooks As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
        Dim r As Byte
        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(chkListPath)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBooks.Worksheets("Tasks")
        rng = xlWorkSheet.Range("A2")
        r = 0
        Do While rng.Offset(r).Value <> ""
            Try
                newChk = chkListContainer.Items.Item(r)
            Catch
                chkListContainer.Items.Add(New Controls.CheckBox)
                newChk = chkListContainer.Items.Item(r)
                newChk.Content = rng.Offset(r).Value
            End Try
            Try
                If rng.Offset(r, 1).Value = True Then
                    newChk.IsChecked = True
                End If
            Catch

            End Try
            r = r + 1
        Loop
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks.Close()
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkTimer()
    Dim dispatcherTimer As DispatcherTimer = New DispatcherTimer()
    AddHandler dispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)
    dispatcherTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    chkListGetData()
    chkListSendData()
End Sub
```

In my testing, this has worked fine, but I have a feeling that when lots of people are using the program, this will not work so well when multiple people attempt to update the file at the same time. If I'm wrong and this code is perfect, that's great, but I doubt that is the case. If there's a better way to handle this kind of thing, I would love to learn how to implement it in this program.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Comment: since excel seems to be a major element in this, you might want to add some tags

Comment: You are using an Excel file as a database. Excel is not very well suited as a database. You may end up with concurrency issues if multiple users are trying to update their tasks (you realized this already). You should look into a real database such as MSSQL, MySQL, or Access.

Comment: Additionally, there are many project management tools out there. Surely, you could find one that costs less than what your company will pay you to develop one. Your boss may appreciate you finding a professional alternative to paying you to reinvent the wheel! No offense :)

Comment: As Verdolino says - please, don't use Excel!  A custom built database will work much better, Outlooks Task tracker will do a better job, pen and pencil will give you less hassle, an internet search for "project management software" throws up better results.  Anyway, please find another way (17 years experience in Excel says use something else!)